# Полет картинки в корзину?

Tags: jquery

Всем привет. Реализовал полет картинки товара в корзину, все работает нормально

```
var cart_offset = $("#cart").offset(); //координаты корзины
   var cart_img = $this.parents('.product').find('img.boss');
   console.log(cart_img);
     $('<style id="transferEffect" type="text/css">' + '.ui-effects-transfer { z-index:10000000; opacity:0.5; border:1px solid #000000; background-image: url(' + $(cart_img).attr('src') + '); }' + '</style>').appendTo('head');
    $(cart_img).effect("transfer", {
        clone: cart_img,
        to: $("#cart")
    }, 750);
```

Просмотреть можно [тут](http://cosmetica-optom.kz/catalog/bytovaya_himiya/sredstva_dlya_mytyya_posudy)

Но есть прикол, картинка улетает но не сживаемтся в размере? как сделать так что бы она уменьшалась в размере?

Comment: добавь: background-size: cover

Comment: супер! Помогло!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

добавь: background-size: cover